# awk как справиться с quote?

Tags: linux, awk

надо поменять эту строку

```
hello name="hi">
```

на эту

```
hello name="hi" perm="fe">
```

пробвал это, но он постоянно ругается.

```
awk -f '/\">/ perm=\"fe\">' file
```

Comment: А если так: sed 's,>, perm="fe">,'

Answer (score 0):

А обязательно awk? perl не пойдет?

```
cat file-input.htm | perl -pe 's/>/ perm="fe">/g' > file-output.htm

perl -pe 's/>/ perm="fe">/g' <file-input.htm >file-output.htm

perl -pe 's/>/ perm="hi">/g' <<<$(curl https://stackoverflow.com/)
```

Через awk тоже можно, но не так эстетично. Там есть функции `sub()` и `gsub()`:

```
awk '{gsub(/>/," perm=\"hi\">");}1' <<<$(curl https://stackoverflow.com/)
```